# How to clean up this string in python with strip?

Tags: python, regex

This is my input string

```
    string = "data here\n            "\
"\n        \n      another_data\n            \n            more data\n"
```

I've tried using `strip` like below

```
string = string.strip("  \n")
```

However when i print it, the data is unchanged

```
print repr(string)
```

Ideally, I'd like to format the data in a list like this `["data here","another data","more data"]`

I do not want to use `regex` functions, how can i get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one liner can be:

```
In [20]: [s.strip() for s in string.splitlines() if s.strip()]
Out[20]: ['data here', 'another_data', 'more data']
```

to make it a plain for-loop:

```
In [21]: res=[]
    ...: for s in string.splitlines():
    ...:     clean_s = s.strip()
    ...:     if clean_s:
    ...:         res.append(clean_s)
    ...:         

In [22]: res
Out[22]: ['data here', 'another_data', 'more data']
```

Comment: @Clodion Nope, this is the best one here

Answer (score 1):

```
st = "data here\n            "\
    "\n        \n      another_data\n            \n            more data\n"
st = st.split()
print(st)
```

result:

```
['data', 'here', 'another_data', 'more', 'data']
```

And don't use string as variable!!

Comment: why don't use 'string'? And that's not the OP's expected output ;(

Comment: @clodion this corrupts the data by splitting it individually, not what the OP wanted

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

You may use `re.split`

```
>>> string = "data here\n            "\
"\n        \n      another_data\n            \n            more data\n"
>>> [i for i in re.split(r'\s*\n\s*', string) if i]
['data here', 'another_data', 'more data']
```